# Differing lengths when using R function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am wondering why my function returns an error that my arguments have differing lengths when I know they do not. The function should create tables that compare a vector to several other vectors belonging to the same data.frame using a for loop. Some sample data and function is below...thanks for any help in advance.

```
mbr.type <- c('New_Mbr', 'Zero_Mbr','newSingle', 'newJoints', 'singleApp')

structure(list(singleApp = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), cgrp = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), B1_CreditScore = c(651, 
636, 793, 453, 672, 656, 622, 796, 0, 729, 714, 779, 560, 627, 
791, 674, 693, 640, 646, 640), Join_Days = c(4953, 0, 13485, 
3749, 862, 4394, 689, 2561, 1766, 1507, 6314, 3093, 3942, 6223, 
210, 7138, 3002, 3996, 2811, 0), Collection = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CREDIT_LIMIT = c(500, 
5000, 15000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15000, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 
0, 0, 0), HighestJointScore = c(0, 0, 0, 832, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 669, 0, 0, 0, 542, 662, 0, 729), New_Mbr = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), product = c("cc", 
"cc", "cc", "pl", "pl", "pl", "pl", "cc", "cc", "pl", "pl", "pl", 
"pl", "pl", "pl", "pl", "pl", "pl", "pl", "pl"), Zero_Mbr = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), newSingle = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), newJoints = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), joint = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), collSSNMbr = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), id = c("151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", "151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df", 
"151aff42b0f2d2654d39df270ab411df")), .Names = c("singleApp", 
"cgrp", "B1_CreditScore", "Join_Days", "Collection", "CREDIT_LIMIT", 
"HighestJointScore", "New_Mbr", "product", "Zero_Mbr", "newSingle", 
"newJoints", "joint", "collSSNMbr", "id"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>, row.names = c(15794L, 
13346L, 7703L, 1024L, 10068L, 9268L, 9262L, 11227L, 16059L, 11861L, 
13763L, 1307L, 928L, 9111L, 5086L, 4715L, 6832L, 6104L, 7193L, 
1292L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

tableList <- function(x, y, data, ...){
   if(!is.character(y)){
      stop('y must be a character vector')
   }

   if(!all(mbr.type %in% colnames(data))){
      stop('all y must be included in data')
   }

   if(!is.character(x)){
      stop('x must be a character vector')
   }

   table.list <- list()
   my.call <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
   my.call[[1]] <- as.name('table')
   #data <- data
   my.call[['x']] <- data[[x]]

   for(i in 1:length(y)){

      my.call[['y']] <- data[[y[i]]]
      table.list[[i]] <- eval(my.call)
   }
}

 tableList(x = 'Collection', y = mbr.type, data = sampleSO)
```

> Error in table(x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
>     all arguments must have the same length b

Comment: What is `allProducts`?

Comment: `table(1:4, 1:3)` throws the same error, for the same reason: `nrow(data) != length(mbr.type)`.

Comment: @r2evans I'm not sure this applies here. My function passes the entire 'Collection' vector to argument x and the entire vector for each element of string mbr.type to argument y. It loops through every element has an equal length to 'Collection'.

Comment: I thought that was precisely the point: your two vectors are not equally sized, a prerequisite for `table()` (unless I'm misunderstanding things). The entire `Collection` vector is length 20, and `mbr.type` is length 5.

Comment: yes, you are misunderstanding. The mbr.type vector contains 5 elements each a column of the data. The loop should take the 1st element of mbr.type - 'New_Mbr' and compare that column which has a length of 20 to the 'Collection' column which has a length of 20. After the loop 5 tables should be included in a list that compared each element of mbr.type to 'Collection'.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already run this:

```
library(plyr)
```

And I'm assuming allProducts might look something like this:

```
allProducts <- cbind("Prod 1", "Prod 2", "Prod 3", "Prod 4", "Prod 5")
colnames(allProducts) <- c('New_Mbr', 'Zero_Mbr', 'newSingle', 'newJoints', 'singleApp')
```

I think the problem is that it is attempting to pass an `expand.dots` argument to the table function. Since this is not a valid argument name, it's trying to include `TRUE` in the table, the length of which is not equal to your `x` or `y` (20).

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.... Would this solve your problem?...

```
tableList <- function(myx, myy, data, ...) {
if (!is.character(myy)) {
    stop('y must be a character vector')
}

if (!all(mbr.type %in% colnames(allProducts))) {
    stop('all y must be included in data')
}

if (!is.character(myx)) {
    stop('x must be a character vector')
}

table.list <- list()

x <- data[[myx]]

for (i in 1:length(myy)) {
    y <- data[[myy[i]]]
    table.list[[i]] <- table(x, y)
}
table.list
}

tableList(myx = 'Collection', myy = mbr.type, data = sampleSO)
```

Comment: My error. allProducts should be 'data'. Just an error check to ensure the columns names listed in mbr.type exist in the data.